# Using QueryBuilder and getting "QueryBuilder is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, redquerybuilder

I have query builder sort of working but when I pull up the console the error I get is

> QueryBuilder is not defined

Am I missing a reference to a JS library or am I loading my JS in the wrong order? Here's my javaScript order:

```
1.  doT.js
   2. doU.js
   3. jQuery.extendext.min.js
   4. query-builder.min.js
   5. sql-support (plugin.js_)
   6. sql_parser.js
   7. browser.js
   8. grammar.js
   9. lexer.js
   10. nodes.js
   11. parser.js
   12. defaults.js
   12. template.js
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the file name and line number shown with the error? That should quickly tell you if the calling file is loaded before the library which is likely the case

Comment: It's saying it for sql-support (Line 9), default.js (Line 4) and template.js (line 3).  These are all QueryBuilder files.  Maybe I am missing a JS file?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your console shopwing the warnings?

Comment: Here you go:  http://imgur.com/9FqKr5P

Comment: NB This is not redquerybuilder

Comment: No this is not redquerybuilder.  This is just QueryBuilder.

Comment: Anyone got ideas on this one?  I think I am missing a JS file but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that needs to be included is doT.js, jQuery.extendext.min.js and query-builder.min.js.  Or, you can just use query-builder.standalone.min.js and you don't have to include the doT.js or extendext.js.  Now no more errors.